# Would Firebase be a good choice as a server for the Flutter mobile game I'm creating?

Tags: android, mobile, flutter, server

I am building a turn-based Flutter game. Would Firebase be a good choice as a server for the game? I would like for the players to create logins for their accounts and receive push notifications when it is their turn. Any advice is appreciated. Also, if there is a good beginner tutorial on how this works, that would be super helpful

I have read some online information about Firebase, but I am new to this concept and it sounds like it may work, but I am not sure.

Comment: Opinion type questions normally dont belong on StackOverflow. Use whatever you think will work for your application. Firebase will work, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase should work fine for your game, as far as I can tell. You can refer to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/firebase/index.htm for more information about Firebase, if you need any. There are also several YouTube videos and resources for Firebase beginners.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the feedback